# React-query useQuery executing multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a page which executes multiple API calls - `fetchPreviousOverallStatus`

When a user clicks on a Card, a modal opens and makes another API call - `fetchPreviousData`

What I am noticing is the initial API call (`fetchPreviousOverallStatus`) is being called multiple times. Even when I clear the network requests from Chrome.

What I would like to do is when the user arrives on a page, call several APIs only once and then call the others if a user clicks on a Card which opens a modal and displays the results.

I have this working without react-query but would like to use other features of the library.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useMemo} from "react"
import Card from "../Common/Card"
import {useSelector} from "react-redux"
import Overlay from "../Common/Overlay"
import axios from "axios"
import {apiSubDirectory} from "../../Constants"
import {useQueryClient, useQuery} from "react-query"

export default function OverallOrderCommunicationServiceStatus() {

    const onSuccess = (data) => {
        console.log("Perform side effect after success", data.data)
    }
    const onError = (error) => {
        console.log('Perform side effect after error', error)
    }

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [dataToFetch, setDataToFetch] = useState("");
    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

    const environmentMapping = useSelector(
        (state) => state.env.environmentMapping
    );

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    const urlOverallPreviousStatus = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`

    const fetchPreviousOverallStatus = () => { return axios.get(urlOverallPreviousStatus) }

    const { isLoading, data, isError, error, isFetching, refetch } = useQuery('overallPreviousStatus', fetchPreviousOverallStatus, {
        onSuccess,
        onError,
        enabled: true
    })


    const fetchPreviousOcsTestResults = () => {
        return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?a=${environmentMapping[0].previous.environment}`)
    }

    const { isLoading:isLoading1, data:data1, isError:isError1, error:error1, isFetching:isFetching1 } = useQuery('previousOcsTestResults', fetchPreviousOcsTestResults, {
        onSuccess,
        onError,
        enabled: false
    })

    const fetchPreviousData = async () => {
        await queryClient.refetchQueries('previousOcsTestResults');
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isOpen) {
            if (dataToFetch === "previous") {
                fetchPreviousData();
            }
        }
    }, [isOpen]);


    const columns = useMemo(() => [
        {
            Header: "Status",
            accessor: "title",
        },
    ], [])

    const handlePopupOpen = (dataToFetch) => {
        setIsOpen(true);
        setDataToFetch(dataToFetch);
    };

    const handlePopupClose = () => {
        setIsOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 ml-sm-auto col-lg-12 mt-5">
                    <div className="row mt-5">
                        <div className="card-group">
                            <Card
                                environmentName={environmentMapping[0].previous.environment}
                                releaseno="Environment"
                                onClick={() => handlePopupOpen("previous")}
                            />

                            {environmentMapping[0].previous.isEnvironmentReady ? (

                                isOpen && (
                                    <Overlay
                                        environment={environmentMapping[0].previous.environment}
                                        //release_overlay={modal}
                                        onClose={handlePopupClose}
                                        show={isOpen}
                                        columns={columns}
                                        apiData={apiData}
                                    />
                                )
                            ) : (
                                <React.Fragment />
                            )}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

---

I have tried with no luck:

```
useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            // Disable the query when the component unmounts
            queryClient.getQueryCache().getQuery('overallPreviousStatus').setState({ enabled: false });
        };
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I am noticing is the initial API call (fetchPreviousOverallStatus) is being called multiple times. Even when I clear the network requests from Chrome.

React Query refetches stale Queries on window focus per default. The moment you switch over to your chrome devtools to clear the network requests, you're focussing out of your browser window. Then, when you come back to it, a window focus event will be triggered.

Only stale Queries will be refetched per default, so the best solution is to set a staleTime for your resource if you're not happy with the default of `staleTime: 0`.

Please also read:

- https://tkdodo.eu/blog/practical-react-query#the-defaults-explained
- https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-as-a-state-manager